# How do you separate a wsgi django/python app server from the web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, amazon-ec2, python, django

I've built a django / python application, running on apache with wsgi, and hosted on a single amazon AWS EC2 instance.

It a custom client application, so low traffic, but one part of my application generates reports, which take a requires more horse power, so I'd like to add an incoming web server which looks at my requests and sends them to one of two application servers.

I am guessing it's not exactly load balancing, because I want to treat the requests for generating documents different from other requests.  So I envision apache on one machine, and django on another...

But how do people do this?

- Do I run a wsgi-based django app on the web server that looks at the request and then forwards it to another machine that is running apache with a wsgi-based django app?
- Or is there some apache mod that forwards on requests from the web server, and then the application run as stand-alone django servers without apache?
- Or can a load balancer (like amazon's elastic load balancer) be configured to do this?

I've been having trouble finding documentation on this - is there something in particular I could be searching for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what I am looking for is FastCGI, which has this capability.  Found the answer on the [Chapter 21: Deploying Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter21/) of the django book, where it says:

> FastCGI is an efficient way of letting an external application serve pages to a Web server. The Web server delegates the incoming Web requests (via a socket) to FastCGI, which executes the code and passes the response back to the Web server, which, in turn, passes it back to the client’s Web browser.

The documents also explain [How to use Django with FastCGI, SCGI, or AJP](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/).  Looks like I can modify the request path and route them to different instances fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: [Deprecated since version 1.7: FastCGI support is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/)

I do the same sort of routing using nginx and running django with gunicorn.

Nginx just acts as a reverse proxy and can route your requests in a bunch of different ways.

Set define and name your upstream app servers:

```
upstream main_site { server         localhost:8000;}
upstream reports   { server         172.16.12.35:8000;}
```

And then route requests accordingly

```
location /reports {
    proxy_read_timeout 1900; #because these requests can take a while
    proxy_pass http://reports;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://main_site;
}
```

I've actually done this with 2 of the same app instances on the same box, when i was DB bound but the app server had plenty of juice, so that the long-running reports wouldn't hold app-server threads.

Even if you still run your app from within apache/wsgi, nginx offers a lot of lightweight flexibility. Check it out.